# HTML 文字の隣にあるテキストボックスが一段下がってしまうのを防ぎたい

Tags: html, css

文字の隣にテキストボックスを配置したいのですが、
画面幅のせいかテキストボックスが文字の下段に移動してしまいます。
これを防ぐ方法はありませんか？
分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

```
<span>
      文字
      <input type="text" style="width:450px;">
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
    文字
    <input type="text" style="width:450px;">
</span>
```

これでいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。